# Printing 2 dictionaries at the same line produces different output compared to separate

Tags: python, selenium

So when I print the dictionaries alone (price[1] and price[2]) they print the desired output (different outputs), but when I print both at the same time in the same line they produce the same output (both are literally the same)

```
price[1] = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, """//div[contains(@aria-label, 'dollars')]""") # Get Prices from Calendar
time.sleep(1.5)
for i in range(3):
    print(str(price[1][i].get_attribute("innerHTML")))
#-----------------------------------------
vero = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//span[contains(text(),'Next')]/following-sibling::button""") # Click The Next Button
vero.click()
time.sleep(3)
print("\n")
#-----------------------------------------
price[2] = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, """//div[contains(@aria-label, 'dollars')]""") # Get Prices from Calendar
time.sleep(1.5)
for i in range(3):
    print(str(price[2][i].get_attribute("innerHTML")))
```

So separated from each other they produces an output like this:

```
$101
$200
$305

$456
$789
$890
```

But when I try to print them in the same line at the end of the code:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(str(price[1][i].get_attribute("innerHTML")) + " <><><>  " + str(price[2][i].get_attribute("innerHTML")))
```

It produces this repetition! :

```
$101 <><><> $101
$200 <><><> $200
$305 <><><> $305
```

How do I produce this desired outcome? :

```
$101 <><><> $456
$200 <><><> $789
$305 <><><> $890
```

Comment: "but when I print both at the same time in the same line they produce the same output (both are literally the same)" The code that sets a value for `price[1]` is `price[1] = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, """//div[contains(@aria-label, 'dollars')]""")`; the code that sets a value for `price[2]` is `price[2] = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, """//div[contains(@aria-label, 'dollars')]""")` Aren't those the same? If you use the same XPath to look up data twice in the same document, why should it give different results?

Comment: Please read [mre] and try to make it possible for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes they are the same xpath that's why in between a "Next button" is pressed and it changes the page and the contents, so the same xpath is used to capture the new content on the second page. I read that maybe the two variables are pointing to the same "object". I'm not entirely sure how that happened if that's the case.

Comment: "I'm not entirely sure how that happened if that's the case." Well, thus far you have the advantage of seeing the code that caused it to happen (if it did). If you show us a [mre], it might be possible for us to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think it will help since I'm almost sure that its related to selenium. The values of "price[1]" change as soon as I do the click "vero.click()" in the middle even though I never changed or declared any changes to price[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your print statements are OK. This should work, otherwise it seems your Web driver is fetching same data for the two prices.

```
Price_values_1 = [] 

for i in range(3):
    Price_values_1.append(str(price[1][i].get_attribute("innerHTML")))
#-----------------------------------------
Price_values_2 = [] 

for i in range(3):
    Price_values_2.append(str(price[2][i].get_attribute("innerHTML")))
```

Comment: Same result :( this is driving me crazy. I have no idea why using them in the same line produces this repetition. I also tried saving them in a CSV in two different columns using f.write and I get the same result, the 2 columns are repeated in the CSV file. I really want to know what is wrong.

Comment: I edit my answer, try where the prints are working.

Comment: Thanks Luis your answer worked. Putting them in separated arrays did the job, at the end I just called those arrays instead. Thank you.